# Import ARIS into Rational System Architect

Tags: aris

My basic problem is finding a way to import from an ARIS model to Rational System Architect. From what I understand from searching the IBM website and Google, it looks like it does not support loading 3rd party tools from XML (although the article is 5 years old and I cannot find anything newer). I have the export of ARIS and the DTD file to go along with it. However when I attempt to import into System Architect I get the following error...

```
The input contained no valid objects.
```

Which in my opinion makes sense - if its not setup to import from other products. But with that being said, does anyone know a way to achieve this? Searching online has yielded very little or poor results thus far.

**Update** - As an additional thought, I have been looking into DDL files. System architect seems to say it will work with them, however I have not been able to find out anything about how to create one using ARIS, or how they are used in general. This may end up being the solution, but sadly I am not well versed in this area yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to have come down to two options.

1. Use a 3rd party tool to mediate the process, and convert it. Basically there is a number of other tools out there (such as ToolBus - which is the only one I found that worked for me) that convert from various applications to a single common model. From there it can be exported back to any application.
2. Depending on the models, the newer versions of SA can import BPMN models directly. Mind this only works for those - nothing else.